# Does the MK axiom of infinity and the Power set axiom hold in the cumulative hierarchy?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Question: Define the cumulative hierarchy inductively as:
$$V_0 = \emptyset$$
For each ordinal $\alpha$: 
$$V_{\alpha+1} = \mathcal{P}(V_\alpha)$$ ie the power set of $\alpha$ and for any nonzero limit ordinal $\lambda$:
$$V_\lambda = \bigcup{\{V_\xi : \xi < \lambda\}}$$

If we use $V_\omega$ and $V_{\omega+1}$ as structures for Morse-Kelley, Do the Morse-Kelley axioms of Power Set and Infinity hold for $V_\omega$ and $V_{\omega+1}$?

My thoughts:
Firstly, $\omega$ is a nonzero limit ordinal and  $V_\omega$ is the power set of naturals.

The MK power set axiom says that the power set of a set is, itself, a set

The MK infinity axiom says that there exists a set $y : (\emptyset \in y) \land (x\in y \Rightarrow x\cup\{x\} \in y)$

$V_\omega$: The power set axiom holds because the power sets of any of the members of $V_\omega$ will themselves be elements of $V_\omega$ and thus sets.

The axiom of infinity holds because $\emptyset = 0$ and $x\cup\{x\} = x+1$ and we know that the successor of a natural number is a natural number and thus will be a member of $\omega$ and certainly a member of $V_\omega$

$V_{\omega+1}$: The power set axiom holds because we know that there are no sets with cardinality between $V_\omega$ & $V_{\omega+1}$ and so for all proper subsets of $V_{\omega+1}$, their power set will either be $V_{\omega+1}$ or a subset of $V_\omega$.

The axiom of infinity holds because, similar to above, $\alpha \subseteq V_\alpha$.

Is my reasoning correct or totally wrong? Also, despite my reasoning above, I am a little confused as I thought the fact the MK axioms are axioms means that it isn't a case of them being true or false.

Thanks

Comment: Fair enough. The question was asked as two separate parts: one whether the two axioms hold in $V_\omega$ and the second question said "now decide for $V_{\omega+1}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The axiom of infinity fails in $V_\omega$. Even though each of the natural numbers is *itself* in $V_\omega$, the set of all of them is not itself a member of $V_\omega$. It only shows up as an element of $V_{\omega+1}$.

In $V_{\omega+1}$ the MK axiom of infinity still fails. You do have $\omega$ as an element of $V_{\omega+1}$, but it is not a "set" (as implicitly demanded by the axiom), since there is no element of $V_{\omega+1}$ that *contains* $\omega$.

> The power set axiom holds because we know that there are no sets with cardinality between $V_\omega$ and $V_{\omega+1}$.

No, we *don't* know that. $V_\omega$ has cardinality $\aleph_0$ and $V_{\omega+1}$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ -- and whether there are cardinalities between these or not is the *continuum hypothesis*. Fortunately this isn't really related to the power set axiom. It holds in the two structures, but not for the reason you claim.

Comment: Thanks so much for that. I thought the axiom of infinity only said that there exists such a set so even if $\omega \notin V_{\omega}$ there would still be such sets. Is this wrong?

Comment: @Andrew: Remember that the axioms are always claims about _what is (or isn't) true inside the model_. When the axiom of infinity says that such-and-such $y$ exists, it means that _there is an element of the structure_ that qualifies as $y$ in the property the axiom states. So it doesn't matter that $\omega$ exists _at the metalevel_ if it's not an element of the structure.

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry to keep asking, your help raised for me another question: if $\omega \notin V_\omega \land \omega \in V_{\omega+1}$, does this mean that the power set of $\omega$ is not actually in $V_{\omega+1}$ and therefore the power set axiom fails in $V_{\omega+1}$?

Comment: @Andrew: Partially right. You're right that $\omega\in V_{\omega+1}$ and $\mathcal P(\omega)\notin V_{\omega+1}$. But this does not mean that the power set axiom fails -- because in the structure $V_{\omega+1}$, $\omega$ _is a proper class_ rather than a set, and therefore the power set axiom is not supposed to apply to it there.